# Single day bookings not registering properly in my booking calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Booking Calendar Bug for single day

There is a bug that I am struggling to fix for my booking calendar.

If I make a booking for a single day, it doesn't get booked. Meaning the date is NOT crossed out for other users.

The 10th is supposed to be booked like the rest of the dates:

[image]

Here is the original code :

```
function wpkGetThisDateSlots( date ) {

    var slots = {
        isFirstSlotTaken: false,
        isSecondSlotTaken: false
    }

    if ( $( '#listing_type' ).val() == 'event' )
        return slots;

    if ( typeof disabledDates !== 'undefined' ) {
        if ( wpkIsDateInArray( date, disabledDates ) ) {
            slots.isFirstSlotTaken = slots.isSecondSlotTaken = true;
            return slots;
        }
    }


    if ( typeof wpkStartDates != 'undefined' && typeof wpkEndDates != 'undefined' ) {
        slots.isSecondSlotTaken = wpkIsDateInArray( date, wpkStartDates );
        slots.isFirstSlotTaken = wpkIsDateInArray( date, wpkEndDates );
    }
    //console.log(slots);
    return slots;

}

function wpkIsDateInArray( date, array ) {
    return jQuery.inArray( date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), array ) !== -1;
}
```

I tried

```
if ( typeof wpkStartDates == typeof wpkEndDates) {

}
```

But that statement didn't do anything

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks

Comment: See also [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), how to make a [mre] of your issue, and the [tour] (since you're new). You can [edit] your post. Thanks.